# How to show an association value in a view?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have a Company class:

```
class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
    validates :name, :presence => true
    has_many :employees
end
```

and an Employee Class where the employee can only be associated with one company:

```
class Employee < ActiveRecord::Base
    validates :lastName, :presence => true
    belongs_to :company
    validates :company, :presence => true
end
```

When I'm listing the employees,

```
<% @employees.each do |employee| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= employee.firstName %></td>      <- works
    <td><%= employee.lastName %></td>       <- works
    <td><%= employee.company.name  %></td>  <- Get an 'undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass' error
  </tr>
<% end %>
```

I thought the employees company was eagerly loaded and I can therefore access the association directly in the object, or is my syntax wrong?

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: What do you mean when you say it fails?

Comment: Sorry Andy, updated the question with the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can think of two scenarios:

1. `company_id = NULL`.
2. `company_id = ID` but the company with this id does not exist anymore.

In any case it's trivial to check in the console the offending object(s): `Employee.reject(&:company)`.

Comment: Doh!  I put the constraint in after and there was one employee with a null value in the DB, removed it and all is good!

Comment: On that note, is there a clean way to prevent this?  Like a tertiary in the view that would substitute "" if there is a null company_id?

Comment: sure, write `employee.company.try(:name) || "No company"`.

Comment: Awesome tokland, much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Since an employee belongs to a company, you should load the employees from the company itself. Something like:

```
class EmployeeController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @employees = @company.employees
    ...
  end
  ...
end
```

Comment: Thanks simone, but the @employees will belong to various companies